# Fullcalander.js Delete an event with google a.p.i calendar

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I am using FullCalendar library to load events in my calendar from Google Calendars. And the Calendar does display the events, but now I want to be able to delete/remove an event that sync with the google calendar. I am looking couple of days now how to do it, but can’t find the answer.

(I know there a couple of people who had the same problem but it doesn’t work for me)
I hope someone can help me find the solution.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

                var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'bootstrap', 'googleCalendar'],
                    customButtons: {
                        myCustomButton: {
                            text: 'custom!',
                            click: function() {
                                alert('clicked the custom button!');
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    header: {  right:  'prev,next today,list,dayGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth', left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton' }, // buttons for switching between views
                    defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
                    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
                    editable: true,
                    eventLimit: true,
                    eventRender: function(eventObj, el) {

                    },
                    // Showing events
                    events:  {!! json_encode($events) !!},
                });

                calendar.render();
            });
```

This is how I load the events:

```
$request->validate([ 'calendar_id' => 'required', ]); 
$gclient = new Gclient; $client = $gclient->client(); 
$cal = Calendar::find($request['calendar_id']); 
$client->setAccessToken($cal->gmail->token); 
$gcal_id = isset($cal->calendar_id) ? $cal->calendar_id : env('GOOGLE_DEFAULT'); 
$g_cal = new \Google_Service_Calendar($client); 
$eventlist = $g_cal->events->listEvents($gcal_id)->getItems();
$events = []; 

foreach ($eventlist as $event) { 
  if ($event->summary == NULL ) { 
    if ($event->location == NULL ) {
      $title = 'default';
    }
    else { 
      $title = $event->location; 
    } 
  }
  else { 
    $title = $event->summary; 
  }

  $events[] = [ 
    'title' => $title, 
    'start' => $event->start->dateTime, 
    'end' => $event->end->dateTime, 
    'id' => $event->id 
  ]; 
}
```

Comment: Your code would doesn't appear to try to do a delete?  I am not sure i understand the question.  Please post your delete code and any error messages you are getting.

Comment: make a function using fullCalendar's eventClick callback, so when the event is clicked on, you send an AJAX request to your server telling it to delete that event (you can get the clicked ID from fullCalendar, check the documentation). Your server can then tell Google Calendar to delete the event as well. It's not clear what, if anything, you have tried or what problem you're actually facing in achieving any of that?

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I don’t have a server or database the information is stored in. I pull all the information directly from the Google a.p.i. What I want is that I am able to delete an event directly from google calendar. Preferably without external tools outside of Laravel, PHP, JavaScript, FullCalander.io unless there is no other way.

Comment: "pull all the information directly from the Google a.p.i. " in that case you can send an Ajax request directly back to the Google API to delete it then, I assume. How did you load the events? You didn't show

Comment: So you **do** have a server - that's PHP code, which only runs server-side. You can use the PHP to talk to Google calendar and delete the event